# Grails Scaffolding Data Not Displayed

Tags: grails

I'm learning Grails. I tried to do scaffolding in Grails. I created a model & controller called EndUser. In my controller I have put:
def scaffold = EndUser;

I created a user here:
http://localhost:8000/ProjectTracker/endUser/create
The record in the MySQL db gets inserted correctly. However, when I tried to list (http://localhost:8000/ProjectTracker/endUser), the list is empty.
How can I check what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class EndUserController {
    static scaffold = true
}
```